# Error occurrs when using setFrame for parent view and autolayout in child view

Tags: ios, objective-c

define a custom view which is pinned to superview by initWithFrame,
and in initWithFrame,I init a button which is pinned by autolayout
this is my code:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
self=[super initWithFrame:frame];
if(self){
    button=[[TBPrimaryButton alloc] init];
    [self addSubview:button];
    [button mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.bottom.mas_equalTo(-20);//.with.priorityMedium();
            make.left.mas_equalTo(13);//.with.priorityMedium();
            make.right.mas_equalTo(-13);//.with.priorityMedium();
            make.height.mas_equalTo(45);//.with.priorityMedium();
    }];

}
return self;
}
```

when running the project,there are constraint conflicts which i can't understand:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

"<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fe5db20d070 TBPrimaryButton:0x7fe5db441a20.left == ConfirmDonationView:0x7fe5db48a430.left + 13>",
"<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fe5db4393c0 TBPrimaryButton:0x7fe5db441a20.right == ConfirmDonationView:0x7fe5db48a430.right - 13>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fe5d8e15b00 ConfirmDonationView:0x7fe5db48a430.width == 0>"
```

i'm pretty sure i didn't add any other constraints

thank you for ur time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about library you're using, but you can try to add

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

before adding constraints